# Wpf start in primary screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If user has multiple screens,

how can I start application in primary screen or chosen screen at start up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heres the basic code. It uses WinForms but I dont know of a pure WPF solution.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Foo
{
    public class WindowUtility
    {
        public static void MoveToMonitor(Window window, int monitorId, bool maximize)
        {
            Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;

            int screenId = monitorId - 1;

            if (screens.Length > 1 && screenId < screens.Length)
            {
                var screen = screens[screenId];
                var area = screen.WorkingArea;

                if (maximize)
                {
                    window.Left = area.Left;
                    window.Top = area.Top;
                    window.Width = area.Width;
                    window.Height = area.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    window.Left = area.Left;
                    window.Top = area.Top;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The code origionally used a config value (string).

Answer (score 4):

See this MSDN question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/316c001b-0511-4c18-8e26-d46021381ae6

You can find information about the primary screen in SystemParameters.PrimaryScreen* Then you can use Window.WindowStartupLocation or for a specific point you can use the W32 APIs and use SetWindowPos to position your screen on start up.

Comment: Well there is no quickfix, but if you research these classes you should be able to write some code to do this. I don't have a ready made code sample for you though, but where would the fun in that be ;).

Comment: If I want select screen what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, **save the current window location to Isolated Storage** and then at startup time **restore the window to the same location** (if you can find a window location stored in isolated storage). Use the **Window.WindowStartupLocation** as Roy T suggested. This should work across multiple monitors as well.

Comment: Good point, I hate it when programs don't start where I left them :).

Answer (score 1):

This is my purely WPF solution to center a Window on the primary monitor with a border of empty space around it (because I don't want it maximized).  My setup is a square-ish monitor on my left and a widescreen on my right.  This was tested with each monitor being set as the primary monitor in Windows.

Before I get to that solution, there are three useful properties on `System.Windows.SystemParameters` that give various heights.  The numbers given are for my 1920x1080 widescreen.

- `PrimaryScreenHeight` - 1080.  The actual resolution height set in Windows.
- `WorkArea.Height` - 1040.  The actual resolution height minus the Start Bar
- `FullPrimaryScreenHeight` - 1018. The actual resolution minus the Start Bar and minus the Window header.

This is my solution and I use `WorkArea.Height`:

```
    protected T SetWindowLocation<T>(T window) where T : Window
    {
        //This function will set a window to appear in the center of the user's primary monitor.
        //Size will be set dynamically based on resoulution but will not shrink below a certain size nor grow above a certain size

        //Desired size constraints.  Makes sure window isn't too small if the users monitor doesn't meet the minimum, but also not too big on large monitors
        //Min: 1024w x 768h
        //Max: 1400w x 900h

        const int absoluteMinWidth = 1024;
        const int absoluteMinHeight = 768;
        const int absoluteMaxWidth = 1400;
        const int absoluteMaxHeight = 900;

        var maxHeightForMonitor = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - 100;
        var maxWidthForMonitor = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - 100;

        var height = Math.Min(Math.Max(maxHeightForMonitor, absoluteMinHeight), absoluteMaxHeight);
        var width = Math.Min(Math.Max(maxWidthForMonitor, absoluteMinWidth), absoluteMaxWidth);

        window.Height = height;
        window.Width = width;
        window.Left = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth - width) / 2;
        window.Top = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight - height) / 2;
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

        return window;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my borderless window implementation. You should be able to interpret this if you need any differences. I make the window 1/2 the size of my primary monitor then center it. Make sure WindowStartupLocation is set to Manual.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / 2;
    Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 2;
    Left = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - Width) / 2;
    Top = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - Height) / 2;
}
```