# Run application on mutliple displays c# on W7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, multiscreen

I have multi (2 and more) display(screen) system and I need to define on which screen the application will start and how it will behave. For 1st scenario behavior displays can be replaced, thus the resolution can differ. For second scenario all the displays are the same.

behavior scenarios:
1st - an application with two (only) completely different screens.
2nd - an app with the matrix of displays (let say 4x3)

Is it possible to control on which display (screen) the application will start? Can I do the application maximized only on one display? And am I able to maximize the application on all displays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wpf start in primary screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324276/wpf-start-in-primary-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324276/wpf-start-in-primary-screen)

You can Access to screens with Screen.AllScreens;
the you can do what you want with each screen.

for maximizing you should do this manually with width and height of screens