# Run different applications on 2 monitors

Tags: c#

I have this C# project I'm working on, where I need to launch some videos on the second monitor and my application on the main monitor.

Is this possible to be done in C#? Launch some videos on monitor 2 in full screen and launch my application windows in full screen also.

So basically, I need to know how can select a specific screen and do something on it also how can I make an application launch in full screen.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation?

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324276/wpf-start-in-primary-screen

Comment: I don't mind any, I've worked with both so the easier and better way to do this job will be picked. I didn't start with the project yet. Tomorrow, I will start with it.

Comment: If it's a new application, I would definitely choose WPF.

Comment: Use WPF, it's by far the more modern and easy to use system.

Answer (score 0):

It should actually be possible using Direct3D i think, while not having done this myself.

You should be able to identify your monitors, and do the appropriate work on each of them.

In your case I would create two different Direct3D Devices with each it's own resources (sharing resources between two different Devices doesn't seem to be possible).

Here are some Direct3D Samples on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153298(v=vs.85).aspx

And here you can find a way to creat a Direct3D Device on MSDN too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153258(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback !
I have edited my post in order to clarify it. :)