# Force splash screen to be in same place as startup window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have an image that is my splashscreen in my project. I did so by changing the build action to 'SplashScreen'.

In my application I start up the main `OnStartup` function by doing some background setup, and then ending with this:

```
mainWindow.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
mainWindow.Show();
```

The `mainWindow` is set to show on `CenterScreen`. However, when running, the program shows the splashscreen on one monitor and the program on another.

How can I set it up so that the screen shows up right on top of where the `mainWindow` will pop up within the monitors?

Comment: The WPF SplashScreen class is hard-coded to be displayed on the center of the primary monitor.  No knobs to tweak.  As long as you keep using it, you're doomed to have to display your main window [on the primary monitor as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324276/wpf-start-in-primary-screen).

Comment: @HansPassant I guess the answer to this will be to force the main window to the primary monitor (which is fine by me). Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, Splash screens are bad for usability. Is there any way you can modify your software to not require a splash-screen?

Comment: @Dai Yes. However, it is a customer's request.